# Updating State dynamically with React using Checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I have a checkbox called Animal. When the checkbox is selected, this.state.Animal is set to true and the animal-filter div is shown.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.Animal} onChange={this.checkAnimal} /> Animals 
{this.state.Animal ? 
<div className="animal-filter">
<div className="checkbox">
  <p><input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.dog} onChange={this.checkdog} /> AA </p>
    </div>
    <div className="checkbox">
  <p><input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.cat} onChange={this.checkcat} /> A</p>
    </div>
    <div className="checkbox">
  <p><input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.fish} onChange={this.checkfish} /> B</p>
    </div>
</div> : null}
```

My problem is that I want these checkboxes of cat, dog and fish to be set to true instantly once the animal state is set to true. I know that react setState does not update the state automatically so how would I make it such that, when the animal checkbox is "checked" the other checkboxes are set to true vice versa?

My code for updating state:

```
checkAnimal(){
  this.setState({animal: !this.state.animal});   
   if (this.state.animal !=true){
     this.setState({
      cat:false,
      dog:false,
      fish:false,
   });
   }else{
     this.setState({
       cat:true,
       dog:true,
      fish:true,
   });      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The`checkAnimal` method can be drastically simplified to

```
checkAnimal() {
  this.setState({
    animal: !this.state.animal,
    cat: !this.state.animal,
    dog: !this.state.animal,
    fish: !this.state.animal,
  });   
}
```

This will guarantee that when the animal checkbox is checked, the cat, dog and fish checkboxes will stay in sync with it's state.

Also, there are references to `this.state.Animal` with a capital `A` in the jsx which is incompatible with `this.state.animal` as it is accessed in the `checkAnimal` method.

e.g. `{this.state.Animal ?` so watch out.

Consider using a JavaScript code linter like eslint to catch errors like that.

Comment: Thanks for the refactoring advice, this was helpful

Comment: No problem, please consider marking my answer as the accepted answer if it helped you resolve the issue!